# Breaking RSA with Factor in Range of $\sqrt{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

Suppose one of the RSA prime factors $p$ is the range of $\sqrt{N}$, in particular it holds that $|p-\sqrt{N}|<\sqrt[4]{N}$

I want to show that RSA can be broken in time poly(log N)

Given hint: $N = pq = (\frac{p+q}2)^2 - (\frac{p-q}2)^2 $ , also $\frac{p+q}2 \approx \sqrt{N}$

$\textbf{This is my approach:}$

First of all, we can calculate $\sqrt{N}$

From $|p-\sqrt{N}|<\sqrt[4]{N}$ we know that $p$ can only be $2 \sqrt[4]{N}$ distinct values, namely anything in$ \{\sqrt{N}- \sqrt[4]{N}, ...,\sqrt{N} + \sqrt[4]{N} \}$

Of course $\sqrt{N}$ is usually not a whole number, but we can round up

So now we can test for every element $p$ in this set, if $p | N$ , in which case we could easily calculate the other factor

If i am not mistaken, this reduced bruteforce would cost $\mathcal{O} ( \sqrt{N} )$ , which does not seem to match with what we want to show, e.g. $\mathcal{O} ( \sqrt{N} )$ $\not=$ poly(log N)

Comment: You have $2\root4\of N$ possible values of $p$, so how do you get a cost that's big-oh of $\sqrt N$?

Comment: $\mathcal{O} ( \sqrt[4]{N}) $ would still be not, what we want to show

Comment: we only have to test values that are 1 or 5 modulo 6 ...

Comment: How does help in reducing the time? Even if we only need to test one third of all values, it'd still be the same time complexity

Comment: the number of tests if you know the primes, is never more than it would be for the first $2\sqrt[4]{N}$ natural numbers

Comment: my point is you don't actually brute force check .